# Select latest measurement results

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a [`PostgreSQL`](http://www.postgresql.org/) database table containing measurement results. Every measurement has a time column the measurement has been performed on, a metrics column containing the results from that measurement and an identifier identifying the object being measured.

Since the table contains multiple measurements for the same object, I want to only select the latest measurement of each object.

My approach was to order by the identifier and mess time descending and finally to eliminate duplicates retaining only the first row for each identifier. I also only want the metrics column to be returned. How is it done?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(id) FROM measurements ORDER by id, messon DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Not only does this query take a while, the resulting rows are also only tilde (`~`) symbols:

```
(10 rows)

~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

I'm using [`Ubuntu`](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: The tildes just show the rest of the output is blank.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to say which columns you want to see:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(id) * FROM measurements ORDER by id, messon DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Note the asterisk in the statement.

As to the speed issue, have you created an [ordered index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html) on the id and messon columns?

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY id_messon_desc_idx ON measurements (id DESC, messon DESC);
```